# prefill sessionstorage with some test data (only when sessionstorage is empty)

Tags: javascript, testing, session-storage

How am I supposed to prefill my sessionStorage with test data and why should I do that? (this is the task which I need to do). Can you give me some examples of it?

Answer (score 0):

E.g. check with getItem if variable is empty, if empty setItem:

```
if(!sessionStorage.getItem('key')) sessionStorage.setItem('key','123value');

console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('key'))
```